# Fast read of svmlight file by chunks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big text file in svmlight format. It contains strings of space separated pairs of indices (int) and values (float) separated by semicolon.

Example:

```
1:2 4:12 5:3 ...
2:34 4:2 12:5 ...
```

A file can be very big and it is not possible to read it whole at once in numpy array.

How to read such a file by chunks most efficiently? Or maybe the more correct question is how effiently create numpy array in such situation?

For now I use the following code. `lines` is a list of lines read from the file.

```
    x = []
    for line in lines:
        tmp = re.split('[ :]', line)
        out = [0] * len(self.__varnames)
        for i in range(0, len(tmp), 2):
            out[int(tmp[i])] = float(tmp[i+1])
        x.append(out)
    x = np.asarray(x)
```

It is pretty fast relative to my other attempts but I believe that it can be speed up.

NOTES:

1) `load_svmlight_file` from sklearn package reads file as a whole and it fails to read a file without leading class label which is optional.

2) I expect to find a fast solution without dependencies from external libraries (if such exist). But `numpy`, `scipy` are allowed of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can yield lines of read in chunks.

Here a simple solution for both cases.

```
def yield_file(infile):
    '''(file_path) >> line
    A simple generator that yields the lines of a file.
    '''

    with open(infile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line


def read_in_chunks(infile, chunk_size=1024):
    '''(file_path, int) >> str
    Simple generator to read a file in chunks.
    '''

    with open(infile,'r') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not solve the speed issue. Speed limitation is an array creation. I mentioned 'read file by chunks' to avoid advices to use functions from well-known packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bit cleaner and don't need the regex:

```
x = []
for line in lines:
    out = [0] * len(self.__varnames)
    for entry in line.split():
        index, value = entry.split(':')
        out[int(index)] = float(value)
    x.append(out)
x = np.array(x)
```

No idea if this is any faster. Need to test.

Comment: Thanks. The speed is almost the same. Maybe for very long strings there will be some difference.

Comment: Might be limited the speed of hard drive. Compare with an empty loop.: `for line in lines: pass` for your large file.